# How to move alist with powershell from one site to a subsite?

Tags: powershell

I havent found how to move or at least copy  a list with its content from one site to a subsite.

The copy/move needs to copy with versioning included.

No clue where/how should I start

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can highly recommend Gary LaPointe's Cmdlets for this: [SharePoint Automation: Copy-SPList](http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx?Version=SP2010&Cmdlet=Copy-SPList)

Downloadable from here: [SharePoint Automation: Downloads](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/)

Although Gary notes that the above cmdlet is based on the built-in [Export-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx) and [Import-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx) cmdlets:

> Wraps the functionality of the Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb cmdlets.